# Laravel Storage::exists($filename) getting false on AWS S3 for .csv, .doc,.xls,.xlsx, .docx files extensions

Tags: laravel, amazon-s3

I am using Laravel 8.

Packages:

```
"guzzlehttp/guzzle" 7.4.5
"league/flysystem-aws-s3-v3" 1.0.3
"league/flysystem" 1.1.9
```

I can upload any file to S3.

I can get a list of all uploaded files.

**I can check if exist and read files with .txt extension !!!!!**

But if i do Storage::exist('filename.csv'); I am getting false.

The same with .doc,.xls,.xlsx, .docx files extensions.
How to solve it?

Comment: What is the default storage disk? is it S3? if not, you should specify the disk `Storage::disk('s3')->exist(...)`

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the s3 disk

```
$fileExists = Storage::disk('s3')->exists($filePath);
```